# Поле ввода текста с 3 состояниями как на Facebook

Tags: jquery, css

Помогите с примером поля ввода текста с 3 состояниями как на Facebook. 1 состояние - поле с подсказкой темно серого цвета, 2 состояние - мышкой кликнули по полю(без ввода текста) и поле с подсказкой стало светло серым, 3 состояние - ввели текст, остался только текст, подсказки нет. Рабочий пример - на facebook поле для поиска людей мест, в строке меню.

Comment: нашел здесь ответ http://matoilic.github.io/jquery.placeholder/ 2 состояние без светло серого цвета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На HTML5 можно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/w3apr/)

[список поддерживаемых браузеров](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder)

[polyfill'ы](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder) (чтобы поддерживалось в не поддерживаемых браузерах)

Comment: а можно с doctype: xhtml transitional ?

Comment: или например с java script?

Comment: ну полифиллы они как раз на js.  Но там где можно css лучше без js обходиться.